# Android access onRestoreInstanceState from onRestart

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I am creating an android app with a timer.

When I change orientation, `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` are called, which is great. However when I press the home button only `onSavedInstanceState` is called, but `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called.

Can I access the saved variables from `onRestart` or perhaps call `onRestoreInstanceState` manually, but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

You do not see `onRestoreInstanceState()` called because Android is not restoring you at that moment. You pressed home, so launcher app should  be brought to front

Comment: Yes I understand that, but can I access savedVariables?